# Ensuring correct time format in bash

Tags: bash, datetime

I have a script which asks the user the following question:

```
read -p "Input time duration of simulation in HH:MM:SS format" -e Time
```

Now how do I ensure the user entered the correct form for $Time
before the variable $Time is actually used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to check hour < 24, minutes < 60, seconds < 60?

```
read -p "Input time duration of simulation in HH:MM:SS format " -e Time

while :; do
  if [[ $Time =~ ^([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})$ ]]; then
    if (( BASH_REMATCH[3] < 60 ))\
       && (( BASH_REMATCH[2] < 60 ))\
       && (( BASH_REMATCH[1] < 24 )); then
       break
    fi
  fi
  read -p "Wrong format. Please use the HH:MM:SS format " -e Time
done

# Do something with $Time
```

Comment: This won't work with 08 and 09 for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0):

You can test it like that :

```
if [[ $Time =~ ^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$ ]]; then
    echo "format is ok"
else
    echo >&2 "format is wrong"
fi
```